# Struggling to understand equals in Figure Group

Tags: java

I have this class which consists in a group that can contain `Circle` and `Triangle`.

```
public class FiguresGroup {
private static final int NUM_FIGURES = 10;
private Figure[] figuresList = new Figure[NUM_FIGURES];
private int numF = 0;

public void add(Figure f) { figuresList[numF++] = f; }

public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numF; i++) {
        s += "\n" + figuresList[i];
    }
    return s;
}

private boolean found(Figure f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numF; i++) {
        if (figuresList[i].equals(f)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean included(FiguresGroup g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < g.numF; i++) {
        if (!found(g.figuresList[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean equals(FiguresGroup g) {
    if (g.included(this) && this.included(g)) return true;
}
```

I don't know how I can implement `equals`. I tried what you see here but it doesn't work. 
For 2 groups to be equal one has to contain every element from the other and vice versa. How to make this work?

Comment: `FigureGroup` would be more readable is proper `hashCode` and `equals` implementations are provided for are involved classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a condition on `numF` of the two objects,
and the `equals` implementation has a compilation error.

Also note that the `found` method (depended upon by `included`) depends on correct implementation of `Figure.equals`.
If it's correctly implemented, then `FiguresGroup.equals` could be fixed this way:

```
  private boolean equals(FiguresGroup g) {
    return numF == g.numF && g.included(this) && this.included(g);
  }
```

Also, `FiguresGroup.equals` doesn't override `Object.equals`, which is confusing. In fact, you're probably already confused by this. When you call `figuresGroup.equals` outside this class, the code compiles,
even though this method is private,
because actually `Object.equals` will be called instead of this private method.

You can fix that by overriding `Object.equals`:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof FiguresGroup)) {
      return false;
    }
    FiguresGroup other = (FiguresGroup) obj;
    return numF == other.numF && other.included(this) && this.included(other);
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, but i created 2 FigureGroups on the Heap (nothing inside them) and tried equals but it returns false, know why?

Comment: public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Figure)) { return false; }
        Figure f = (Figure) o;
        return x == f.x && y == f.y;
    }

Comment: @Mr.Vincent good, so `Figure.equals` looks correct. That was not visible in your post, and it's a requirement for my answer to work. And my last point fixes for you `FiguresGroup.equals`.

Comment: Ahh i see. Im such i noob... And i dont think i've been teached what Overriding is. Anyways thanks for taking the time to answer to me :)

Comment: @Mr.Vincent ok, so do you confirm it works with the updated method I gave you?

Comment: Yes it does but i dont know what override is, so i guess i was meant to do it some other way. But thank you so much

Comment: @Mr.Vincent The `@Override` annotation is optional, but strongly recommended. You can remove it and it will still work.